# Topic subscription of Firebase Cloud Messaging in Android app using Delphi 11

Tags: android, delphi, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an Android app that needs to receive push notifications using Delphi 11. After following the article at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Firebase_Android_Support, I can now register my phone with the FCM service and receive push notifications sent with the specific device token (received from FCM after successful registration). But the article doesn't mention how to make an app subscribe to a topic such that my phone can receive push notifications sent with a topic. Can anyone please share me with a suggestion or pointer for that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for Android, you could use these:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Firebase, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure SubscribeToTopic(const ATopicName: string);
begin
  TJFirebaseMessaging.JavaClass.getInstance.subscribeToTopic(StringToJString(ATopicName));
end;

procedure UnsubscribeFromTopic(const ATopicName: string);
begin
  TJFirebaseMessaging.JavaClass.getInstance.unsubscribeFromTopic(StringToJString(ATopicName));
end;
```

You should probably make sure that the push service has been created before calling these

Comment: On the other hand, this shows the official documentation is quite insufficient because FCM support has been there in Delphi for a few versions already. Embarcadero should address issues like this as a priority.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about documentation, however yes.. it is something that should be addressed. There does not appear to be any feature request in [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22SubscribeToTopic%22)